# how to get the higher value from rows in a range of four columns where there are empty rows

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

[image]

I have this formula that gets the higher number of each row in a four column range.

```
=query(transpose(query(transpose(X3:AA);"Select "&REGEXREPLACE(join("";ArrayFormula(if(len(X3:X);"Max(Col"&ROW(X3:X)-ROW(X3)+1&"),";""))); ".\z";"")&""));"Select Col2")
```

My problem is that I have some rows that are empty and I would like to return the found values in the same row as where the max number was found. 
In another words if the row is empty, nothing should be returned for that row until the next max value is found.
Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0):

remove the `IF`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(X3:AA); 
 "select "&JOIN(","; 
 "max(Col"&ROW(X3:X)-ROW(X3)+1&")"))&""); 
 "select Col2"; 0))
```

Comment: That's close but here is a problem... When there is no value on the first cell x3 all the other positions get thrown off!
it only works if there is data o cell x3
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h6Mi0A_nr7IHhx1cTXWGXW43pI2-rnZxdHqk9-QgA08/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved and thank you for the help.

```
=query(transpose(query(transpose(X3:AA);"Select "&REGEXREPLACE(join("";ArrayFormula("Max(Col"&ROW(X3:X)-ROW(X3)+1&"),")); ".\z";"")&""));"Select Col2";0)
```